JTextPane/JEditorPane displays HTML <!--comment-->
I am using a Java (21) Swing JEditorPane or JTextPane to display a HTML String. This works, but displays HTML comments p.e. <!-- Hidden Text -->.
JEditorPane htmlpane = new JEditorPane();
        htmlpane.setContentType("text/html");
        htmlpane.setText("<html><table><tr><td>Cell 1</td>"
                + "<td>Cell 2</td></tr><tr><td>Cell 3</td>"
                + "<td>Cell 2 A<!--   Hidden Text --> Cell 2 B</td>"
                + "</tr></table></html>");
        panel.add(htmlpane);


(Same result for JTextPane)
I want to display HTML with the comments hidden. (In general: display HTML as close to correct as   possible in a Swing GUI.)

import java.util.regex.Pattern; and do a public static String removeHtmlComments(String html) { return html.replaceAll("<!--.*?-->", "");  }

This behavior seems to be intentional, when the JEditorPane is editable. See this jdk bug entry regarding this topic. There in the comment it is stated: "JEditorPane is supposed to show everything when editable, so the fact that it shows comments is not a bug." And also "Turn off the editable property to have HTML page rendered normally (like in a browser)." So either try to filter out all comments beforehand, or if that is an option for you, disable the editable property of the pane.

JEditorPane is not the same as a Web browser. As far as I know, there is no Swing Web browser - although there are third-party ones. However, JavaFX does have a Web browser.

A JEditorPane or JTextPane will only display up to HTML 3.2.

@mplungjan I might do that -  I totally overlooked that it'd be that simple... (It'd be "" though - as dot usually doesn't match newline).

The behavior you encountered appears to be intentional, for when the JEditorPane is editable.
See the following jdk bug entry regarding this topic: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6422138
There in the comments it is stated:

JEditorPane is supposed to show everything when editable, so the fact that it shows comments is not a bug.

And also:

Turn off the editable property to have HTML page rendered normally (like in a browser).

Your options now are:

either try to filter out all HTML comments beforehand or
disable the editable property of the JEditorPane, since that should also turn off the rendering of HTML comments

